# How to use conditions inside laravel eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

please see my message table schema

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('conversation_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('conversation_id')->references('id')->on('conversations');
        $table->integer('last_sender')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('last_sender')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('msg');
        $table->integer('deleted')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('seen')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And this is the current query I am using

```
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
         ->with(array('last_sender'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','userName','profilePic', 'firstName','lastName');
          }))
         ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
         ->groupBy('conversation_id')
        ->get();
```

As you can see I am Eager Loading `last_sender`. But I want to load it based on a condition. For example, If a user is logged in and his id is 10 and `last_sender` IS NOT=10 then I want to load because I only want to load if the currently logged in user's id is not present in the `last_sender` column.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Message::with([
  'last_sender' => function($q) use ($userId = Auth::user()->id) {
    $q->where('id','!=',$userId)
  }
])->get();
```

to eager load the relation under condition.

```
Message::whereHas(
  'last_sender', function($q) use ($userId = Auth::user()->id) {
    $q->where('id','!=',$userId)
  }
)->get();
```

to load the model instance if it has relation with condition.

Hope this is what you asked for?

Comment: Yes thank you let me see how it works. Thanks again :)

Comment: Beware of the typos :)

Comment: Thank you and it worked. And I am posting this comment for others who may fall into such a problem. For them this is what I used 
`$userId=Auth::user()->id;
        $leftMsg= Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
             ->with(array('last_sender'=>function($query) use ($userId){
                    $query->where('id','!=', $userId);
                    $query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
              }))
             ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
             ->groupBy('conversation_id')
            ->get();`